# C# + COM, modify array in parameter

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I have a COM object in C# and a Silverlight application(escalated privileges) which is a client to this COM object.

COM object:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IProxy
{
    void Test(int[] integers);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Proxy : IProxy
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Test(int[] integers)
    {
        integers[0] = 999;
    }    
}
```

Silverlight client:

```
dynamic proxy = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("NevermindComProxy.Proxy");

int[] integers = new int[5];
proxy.Test(integers);
```

I excpect the integers[0] == 999, but the array is intact.

How to make the COM object modify the array?

**UPD**
Works for non-silverlight apps. Fails for Silverlight. How to fix for silverlight?

Comment: Why are you using COM as an interoperability engine between 2 .NET assemblies? Maybe you should use Assembly.Load instead?

Comment: The goal is to use native code from silverlight application. So I do silverlight -> COMProxy -> native code. As far as I understand silverlight can't pinvoke native code from its sandbox. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: this is beyond my knowledge, sorry. Good luck in finding an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you need to pass the array by ref (see the note in [AutomationFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory%28VS.95%29.aspx) just above the example [arrays are passed by value in C#]) - The problem then is, SL will barf with an argument exception when you call `proxy.Test(ref integers)` (I don't why). The work around is that SL will pass an array by ref if the method takes an object by ref, so this works...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IProxy
{
    void Test( ref object integers);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Proxy : IProxy
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Test(ref object intObj)
    {
        var integers = (int[])intObj;
        integers[0] = 999;
    }
}
```

And with the SL code adding ref like:

```
dynamic proxy = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("NevermindComProxy.Proxy");

var integers = new int[5];
proxy.Test( ref integers);
```

Drop the ref from either the caller or the interface definition and it won't update the array.